# Get selected value of datalist option value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I need to add some values from a `HTML5` `DataList` to a `<select multiple>` control just with Javascript.  But I can't guess how to do it.

This is what I have tried:

```html
<input id="SelectColor" type="text" list="AllColors">
<datalist id="AllColors">
  <option label="Red" value="1">
  <option label="Yellow" value="2">
  <option label="Green" value="3">
  <option label="Blue" value="4">
</datalist>

<button type="button" onclick="AddValue(document.getElementById('AllColors').value, document.getElementById('AllColors').text);">Add</button>
<select id="Colors" size="3" multiple></select>
```

```
function AddValue(Value, Text){

//Value and Text are empty!

var option=document.createElement("option");
option.value=Value;
option.text=Text;

document.getElementById('Colors').appendChild(option);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. I have moved the value selection logic into the method itself.
You will only get the value from the input. You will need to use the value to select the label from the datalist.

```
function AddValue(){
  const Value = document.querySelector('#SelectColor').value;

  if(!Value) return;

  const Text = document.querySelector('option[value="' + Value + '"]').label;

  const option=document.createElement("option");
  option.value=Value;
  option.text=Text;

  document.getElementById('Colors').appendChild(option);
}
```

[Here is the working demo.](https://jsbin.com/yofisud/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the trimmed value of the input. If value is not empty then you can get the selected data list option by matching the value attribute with `querySelector()`.

Try the following way:

```js
function AddValue(el, dl){
  if(el.value.trim() != ''){
    var opSelected = dl.querySelector(`[value="${el.value}"]`);
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = opSelected.value;
    option.text = opSelected.getAttribute('label');
    document.getElementById('Colors').appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="SelectColor" type="text" list="AllColors">
<datalist id="AllColors">
  <option label="Red" value="1"></option>
  <option label="Yellow" value="2"></option>
  <option label="Green" value="3"></option>
  <option label="Blue" value="4"></option>
</datalist>

<button type="button" onclick="AddValue(document.getElementById('SelectColor'), document.getElementById('AllColors'));">Add</button>
<select id="Colors" size="3" multiple></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the selected options's ID in datalist, you can use this code too.

```
<input id="SelectColor" type="text" list="AllColors">
<datalist id="AllColors">
    <option value="Red" id=1></option>
    <option value="Yellow" id=2></option>
    <option value="Green" id=3></option>
    <option value="Blue"  id=4></option>
</datalist>

<script>
$("#SelectColor").change(function(){
  var el=$("#SelectColor")[0];  //used [0] is to get HTML DOM not jquery Object
  var dl=$("#AllColors")[0];
  if(el.value.trim() != ''){
  var opSelected = dl.querySelector(`[value="${el.value}"]`);
  alert(opSelected.getAttribute('id'));
 }
});
</script>
```