# How to determine selected datalist option

Tags: javascript, events, html-input, html-datalist

Is there way to determite, which option from datalist was selected? I mean when I have duplicite names in datalist, see example below:

```
<input type="text" list="cities" id="search-bar" name="city" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="type city">
<datalist id="cities">
        <option value="Olo (PT)" data-city-index="0"></option>
        <option value="Olo (PT)" data-city-index="1"></option>
        <option value="Olonets" data-city-index="2"></option>
        <option value="Olot" data-city-index="3"></option>
</datalist>
```

It is part of weather app, and in some countries, there are cities with same name (but different location) - so how I can distinguih if user have clicked on first or second Olo in example? Is it even possible? I have idea, that maybe is there way to use data attribute, but I dont know if it actually solve my problem (and how...)

Please help.

EDIT:
I understand, that it is for user little bit uncomfortable to actually "don't know" which city they are selecting in datalist, but unfortunatelly I have no way to "help" them (I have only database with city names and longitude and latitude of it). So after selection of city I include link to google maps (for that location) to displaying part

Comment: Seems like, besides the programmatic problem, there's a larger UX problem; how does the user know which one to choose?

Comment: I understand, that it is for user little bit uncomfortable, but unfortunatelly I have no way to "help" them. So after selection of city I include link to google maps (for that location) to displaying part...

Comment: I would suggest using whatever is unique about that city entry as a `data-` attribute(s). For instance, if lat/long are unique, you could add `data-latitude=""` and `data-longitude=""` to the elements. Won't fix the UX, but at least then you'd have the coordinates ready for creating the link (no additional lookup). But index is fine too.

Comment: But do you know, how to get my data-* attribute of selected option on input event? Because this is what I don't know, how to get...

Comment: Hmm... Doesn't look good: [Get selected value of datalist option value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522639/215552)

Comment: But it won't solve my problem...It only works on unique values...

Comment: That's why I said "Doesn't look good" :). You'll have to add something to the city names to make them unique; maybe "Olo (PT) (lat x lon)" or something like that. Or, use a `<select>`, where `<option>` elements are direct children.

Answer (score 0):

you should change value of options in city's name of countries . when user click in list it

```html
<input type="text" list="cities" id="search-bar" name="city" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="type city">
<datalist id="cities">
        <option value="city1 (PT)" data-city-index="0"></option>
        <option value="city2 (PT)" data-city-index="1"></option>
        <option value="city3" data-city-index="2"></option>
        <option value="city4" data-city-index="3"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I cannot simply rename existing city... And adding number looks really strange and ugly...